# FileNotFound exception when trying to get File from resource

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I cannot generate myJasperReports.jasper file because its throwing a `FileNotFoundException` while trying to read the file and create the report. I am using jasper-reports 3.7.5 and annotation-based Spring. Can someone tell what the problem might be?

In web.xml file:

```xml
<bean id="myReportTemplate" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="mypackage/reports/jasper/template/SampleJasper.jasper"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks.

This is the stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mypackage/reports/jasper/template/SampleJasper.jasper] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
[ERROR] at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:179)
[ERROR] at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:48)
[ERROR] at mypackage/reports.ReportsServiceImpl.prepareChart(ReportsServiceImpl.java:93)
[ERROR]
```

The Plugin I'm using in pom.xml file

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exploded</goal>
          </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>

 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>compile-reports</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.5</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: No, I don't think anyone can tell what the problem is, given that you've only said that you "cannot generate [the report] file".  Why can't you generate that file, what happens?  Do you get an exception or some error output that indicates what the problem might be?

Comment: At a bare minimum, post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: This is not `web.xml`, by the way.

Comment: The problem is that the SampleJasper.jasper file is not getting generated in specified folder, the folder itself is not created. Thats its throwing FileNotException while trying to access the file.  How to make sure that SampleJasper.jasper is generated in specified folder.? what kind of plugins or jar i need to get it done.??

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem is solved. The folder structure "mypackage/reports/jasper/template/" should be at classpath level.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the SampleJasper.jasper file is not getting
>   generated in specified folder, the folder itself is not created.

To generate Jasper Report you should call `JasperCompileManager.compileReport()` and you will pass the `.jrxml` file.

But in your case you have are specifying `.jasper` file which means you should have already compiled and placed the compile file in the location which you are providing in your `application-context.xml`.

If you are not precompiling it then you should specify the jrxml file for compilation, then compiled file you will location you will pass to the Jasper viewer.

Spring has documentation on [jasper integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch17s07.html)